# Edit approved email points to localhost

Tags: django, wagtail

After approving a change in the Wagtail admin, the editor receives an email letting them know the page is published. The problem is the link to the page doesn't use the site domain, but localhost:

```
You can view the page here: http://localhost/learn/good-stuff-to-learn/
```

I have both BASE_URL and WAGTAILAPI_BASE_URL configured in my settings.py. Is there another setting I missed?

Django 1.11.10
Wagtail 1.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the domain in the Wagtail admin, under Settings -> Sites.

Comment: Thank you sir! That did the tick :)